# How do you monitor Geth with Prometheus or InfluxDB?

Tags: go-ethereum, monitoring

I've read the v1.9.0 and v1.10.0 blog posts: https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/07/10/geth-v1-9-0/ https://blog.ethereum.org/2021/03/03/geth-v1-10-0/ I didn't read that any of the monitoring features mentioned in the 1.9 post where removed, yet when I try to view http://127.0.0.1:6060/debug/metrics or http://127.0.0.1:6060/debug/metrics/prometheus. So, I assume that these metrics were removed and the documentation wasn't updated. However, when I try these steps for InfluxDB, https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/monitoring-geth-with-influxdb-and-grafana/ , I do not get any measurements when I type `show measurements`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/22646 which might explain my situation.

Comment: I never manage to get InfluxDB to work. A little embarrassing, but I needed to install Prometheus and then it worked. I had thought that Geth included Prometheus.